# Publishing app on the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a student and I've developer an app in Xcode via Virtual Box. I found that Apple Developer Program costs 99$/year, but I'm a student and haven't got enough money. Is there any account sharing or service for less value to publish a free app?

Comment: Google play is £20 for ever. You could use one of thousands apk hosting sites.

Comment: I need to publish my app on App Store, not Play Market :(

Answer (score 3):

You've got a couple of potential routes, depending what you're doing with your apps. As a student, your place of study may be able to help you with the iOS Developer University Program:

https://developer.apple.com/support/university/

There are not any student specific waivers, but if your app is as part of a non-profit, the other route may be to register as such, and then you can use the fee waiver program:

https://developer.apple.com/support/membership-fee-waiver/

If you're planning to make any money from your app however, then the developer licence is gonna cost you, with very little you can do.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, but I'm not based in United States and I guess my university cannot help me, they even not heard about Apple Developer Program itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to apple they **don't have any offers or discount for student** yet as per the below link:

https://developer.apple.com/support/university/

[image]

Other thing you can do is submit a Fee Waiver request to Apple if you’re a nonprofit organization, accredited educational institution, or government entity based in the United States that will distribute only free apps on the App Store as per the below link

https://developer.apple.com/support/membership-fee-waiver/

So I guess you **wont be able to request** for a fee waiver as you are not a not profitable organization or any institute or goverment entity.

Though you can do one thing. You can **sideload your app** on a iPhone and you could show your app to near & dear ones and somehow get a sponsorship for your developer account ;)

If you don't how how to install your app with your apple id in iOS device then this can help you with that:

https://bouk.co/blog/sideload-iphone/

This is a link to an article demonstrating side loading app into iOS device using Xcode7. The procedure is same from then onwards.